# Overflow of an int in f#

Tags: f#, overflow

I am working on some homework and we are supposed to be making a combination function in F#. I have got the factorial function down, but it seems to overflow once I get a big number to use factorial on. (Let's say 20) I understand I can use an int64 or a float, but that would change all the inputs on the code. What data type should I use?

```
let rec Fact (a:int)=
   if (a = 0) then 1 else a*Fact(a-1);;

let combo (n:int) (k:int)=
   if (n = 0) then 0 else (Fact n)/((Fact k)*(Fact (n-k)));;
```

On the code right now, when I do combo 20 5;; it gives me 2147. Which is clearly the wrong answer. I looked at the factorial function and when I put 20 in there it gave me a big negative number. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `20!` is about `2.4 * 10^18`, which is way bigger than `int`, so there is no surprise that you get overflow. Though I don't quite understand what your question is. You're asking which type you should use, but at the same time refuse to use another type. Huh?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, if you want to avoid surprises, you can open the `Checked` module at the top of your file. This will redefine the numerical operators so that they perform overflow checks - and you'll get an exception rather than unexpected number:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Operators.Checked
```

As Fyodor points out in the comment, you cannot fit factorial of 20 in `int` and you need `int64`. However, your `combo` function then performs division which will make the result of `combo 20 5` small enough to fit into `int`.

One option is to change `Fact` to use `int64`, but keep `combo` as a function that takes and returns integers - you'll need to convert them to `int64` before calling `Fact` and then back to `int` after performing the division:

```
let rec Fact (a:int64) =
   if (a = 0L) then 1L else a * Fact(a-1L)

let combo (n:int) (k:int) =
   if (n = 0) then 0 else int (Fact (int64 n) / (Fact (int64 k) * Fact (int64 (n-k))))
```

Now you can call `combo 20 5` and you'll get `15504` as the result.

**EDIT:** As noted by @pswg in the other answer, `int64` is also quite limited and so you'll need `BigInteger` for larger factorials. However, the same method should work for you with `BigInteger`. You can keep the `combo` function as a function that returns `int` by converting back from `BigInteger` to `int`.

Answer (score 2):

You simply won't be able to do that with an 32-bit integer (`int`). A 64-bit integer will get you up to `20!`, but will fail at `21!`. The numbers just get too big, too quickly. To go any further than that you'll need to use [`System.Numerics.BigInteger`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/numerics.biginteger-structure-%5Bfsharp%5D?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) (abbreviated `bigint` in F#).

The parameter can probably stay as an `int` to be reasonable, but you need to return a `bigint`:

```
let rec Fact (n : int) = 
    if n = 0 then bigint.One else (bigint n) * Fact (n - 1)
```

Or to be a little more idiomatic:

```
let rec Fact = function | 0 -> bigint.One | n -> (bigint n) * Fact (n - 1)
```

And now, in your `Combo` function, you'll need to use these `bigint`'s internally for all math (thankfully the integer division is all you need in this case).

```
let Combo (n : int) (k : int) =
    if n = 0 then bigint.Zero else (Fact n) / ((Fact k) * (Fact (n - k)))
```

If you *really* wanted to make `Combo` return an `int`, you can do that conversion here:

```
let Combo (n : int) (k : int) =
    if n = 0 then 0 else (Fact n) / ((Fact k) * (Fact (n - k))) |> int
```

Examples:

```
Combo 20 5 // --> 15504
Combo 99 5 // --> 71523144 (would break if you used int64)
```

**Edit**: By rethinking your implementation of `Combo` you can get some big performance improvements out of this. See [this question on Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202554/how-do-i-compute-binomial-coefficients-efficiently) for the basis of this implementation:

```
let ComboFast (n : int) (k : int) =
    let rec Combo_r (n : int) = function 
        | 0 -> bigint.One 
        | k -> (bigint n) * (Combo_r (n - 1) (k - 1)) / (bigint k)
    Combo_r n (if (2 * k) > n then n - k else k)
```

A quick benchmark showed this to be *significantly* faster than the `Fact`-based version above:

```
Function             Avg. Time (ms)
Combo 99 5            30.12570 
ComboFast 99 5         0.72364
```